# How to add .php extension for particular file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have removed  .php extension in all files of my website. Now $_POST is not sending data to action page. My service provider ask me to add extension of a file extension to use $_POST.I checked by adding .php extension to all my files in .htaccess file  $_POST method works fine. Then  how to add  .php extension to  particular file of my website . Considering my file path as below 
www.example.com/folder/filename
I need
www.example.com/folder/filename.php

My .htaccess file to remove php extension

```
#redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.*)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]
#resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

If I remove the above code $_POST method works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I have removed .php extension in all files of my website" why? and surely if you removed it, you can figure out how to add it back...

Comment: Delete the file and re-upload it with the PHP extension.

Comment: But I need to give extension to one particular file and that file will not shown to user which contains only information to transfer data to database after submitting my form .

Comment: Can you post the code you are using?

Comment: which means .htaccess you are asking for? @starkeen

Comment: Yes ........Your htaccess. :)

Answer (score 0):

To use your file with .php extension ,you'll need to exclude it from rewriteRules . Put the following before  other Rules in your htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^filename\.php$ - [L]
```